# Poly time superset of NP complete language with infinitely many strings excluded from it

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete, structural-complexity

For any arbitrary NP complete language is there always a polytime superset the complement of which is also infinite?

A trivial version which does not stipulate the superset to have infinite complement has been asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50123/42961

For purposes of this question, you can assume that $P \ne NP$.  As Vor explained, if $P = NP$ then the answer is "No".  (If $P = NP$, then $X = \{x \mid x \in \mathbb{N^+} \land x > 1\}$ is NP-complete. Clearly there is no superset of $X$ which is infinite and has an infinite complement, as the complement of $X$ has only a single element.)  Thus we can focus on the case $P \ne NP$.

Comment: If $P = NP$ then $X = \{x \mid x \in \mathbb{N^+} \land x > 1\}$ is NP-complete. Clearly there is no superset of $X$ which is infinite and has an infinite complement (note that $\bar{X} = \{1\}$). So you can "focus" on what happens if $P \neq NP$.

Comment: How about the relativized version: Is there an oracle $A$ s.t. all co-NP$^A$ sets are P$^A$-immune.

Comment: @LanceFortnow ...or for any complete language in a particular. Complexity class, is there always a non trivial superset of a lesser complexity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete set contains an infinite subset in $\mathsf{P}$ assuming that

- pseudorandom generators exist, and
- secure one-way permutations exist.

In other words, assuming that these two conjectures are true, 
no $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete set is P-[immune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_set).
As pointed out in the comments by Lance, 
this is implied by Theorem 4.4 of

- Glasser, Pavan, Selman, and Sengupta, "[Properties of NP-complete sets](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S009753970444421X)",
  SIAM J. Comput. 36(2), 516–542.

(Kaveh has already shown that your question is equivalent to 
whether every $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete sets 
contains an infinite $\mathsf{P}$ subset. 
In other language, 
this is saying that no $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete set is "$\mathsf{P}$-immune." This is the language used in the above-referenced theorem.)

Comment: [ECCC draft](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2004/019/)

Comment: By [strong hard-core functions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.9251&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=6) (and [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator_%28Theorem%29#OWF_.E2.86.92_PRG)), one-way permutations imply pseudorandom generators. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: See Definitions 4.1-4.3 in the cited paper. If I'm understanding correctly, OWPs imply what they call "crypto-PRGs", but not necessarily what they call "PRGs" in the Glasser-Pavan-Selman-Sengupta paper. For their result, they (seem to) need both OWPs and what they call PRGs.

Comment: Kaveh only showed the equivalence to co-NP-complete sets are P-immune, but the conclusion of theorem 4.4 in Glasser et al that all NP-complete sets must have length-increasing reduction, also implies that there are no co-NP-complete P-immune sets.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Thanks...but are there assumptions we can make which in turn imply the non existence of such a language. I was more interested in scenarios where there is no poly time superset

Comment: Please see my answer on above lines http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33450/17763

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. 
The statement

> for every NP-complete $L$, there is $U$ in P such that $L \subseteq U$ and $U^c$ is infinite.

is equivalent to:

> for every NP-complete $L$, complement of $L$ contains an infinite P set.

which is in turn equivalent to

> every coNP-complete set contains an infinite P set.

<strike>which is by symmetry the same as</strike>

> every NP-complete set contains an infinite P-set.

I don't think the answer is known.
I think natural NP-complete sets satisfy this condition easily. 
I don't think we have tools to build an artificial set 
which fails the statement.
 (see Lance's comment below)

Comment: Your initial statement is trivially true. ​ (Let U be the full language.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Its an interesting chain of deductions...Could you give an example of a natural NP complete language in this regard

Comment: The symmetry doesn't make sense. For example, every c.e. set has an infinite computable subset but there are co-c.e.-sets that don't.