# Are there any heuristic-free NP complete problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete, heuristics

Are there any NP complete problems with no infinite subset of instances $\Phi$ such that membership in $\Phi$ can be decided in polynomial time, and for all $x \in \Phi$, $x$ can be solved in polynomial time? (Assuming $P \neq NP$)

Comment: See [this surprising conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman–Hartmanis_conjecture), which is significantly more plausible than its statement sounds, for reasons explained by the article. ​ ​

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See Josh Grochow's answer to [Poly time superset of NP complete language with infinitely many strings excluded from it](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/poly-time-superset-of-np-complete-language-with-infinitely-many-strings-excluded/33316#33316). According to that answer, under some natural cryptographic assumptions, for every co-NP-complete problem there is an infinite subset $\Phi$ of instances such that membership in $\Phi$ is polynomial time, and the decision problem restricted to $\Phi$ is trivial (answer always no).

This can be formalized by stating that no co-NP-complete set is P-immune. It is also known (again under cryptographic assumptions) that no NP-complete set is P-immune. So there is another infinite subset $\Phi'$ such that membership in $\Phi'$ is polynomial-time testable and the decision problem restricted to $\Phi'$ always has answer yes. See e.g. Glasser et al., "Properties of NP-Complete Sets", SICOMP 2006, [doi:10.1137/S009753970444421X](http://doi.org/10.1137/S009753970444421X).

Comment: That's really cool, thanks :). For completeness, those assumptions are: pseudorandom generators exist and secure one-way permutations exist

Comment: @Phylliida : ​ Note that those are using some complexity-theoretic definition for "pseudorandom generator", rather than a usual cryptographic definition. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

A first observation is that having exactly what you ask would be a proof that $P \neq NP$ as it would imply that the set of all instances can not be solved in polynomial time.

However, and I think that is what you meant, we can play a bit with what we mean by "solved in polynomial time". If we mean by it all infinite subsets $\phi$ of instances whose membership is in $P$ are $NP$-complete, then the answer is no by Mahaney's Theorem (http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/06/sparse-sets-tribute-to-mahaney.html). This theorem states that no NP-complete problem can be sparse unless $P = NP$. Now, taking the subset of instances $\{0^i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, we have an infinite sparse subset of instances for which testing membership is in $P$ that cannot be $NP$-complete unless $P = NP$ by Mahaney's Theorem.

Comment: Ah sorry, what I meant is that they can't be solved in polynomial time assuming $P \neq NP$, you're right that that is very important