# What is the relation between P-immune languages and NP-complete languages?

Tags: complexity-classes, fl.formal-languages, computability

Can a NP-complete language be P-immune?

Why can't existence of P-immune languages separate NP from P?

Comment: The question whether a coNP-complete language can be P-immune is discussed at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/poly-time-superset-of-np-complete-language-with-infinitely-many-strings-excluded/33316#33316

Comment: What on earth is the meaning of the first thing ending with a question mark? Is it possible to write it as an English sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that

- pseudorandom generators and secure one‐way permutations exist,

it follows that

- $\mathsf{NP}$‐complete sets are not $\mathsf P$‐immune.

Christian Glaßer, A. Pavan, Alan L. Selman, and Samik Sengupta,
[Properties of NP‐Complete Sets](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S009753970444421X)
SIAM J. Comput., 36(2), 516–542, 2006.